# Which headers are correct to make a non-spam email?

Tags: email, send, email-spam

I'm doing a email sender in node. It's a wrapper for unix [mail tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_(Unix)). I can send emails without a problem but im receiving all my tests in Spam. I'm only using the Content Type and the From in the headers:

```
module.exports = function sendmail(_subject, _to, _html, _from, fn) {
  var command = 'mail -s "$(echo "' + _subject + '\nContent-Type: text/html\nFrom: ' + _from + '")" ' + _to + ' < ' + _html;
  console.log(command);
  exec(command,function (err, stdout, stderr) {
      if (fn) {
        fn(err, stdout, stderr);
      }
    }
  );
};
```

I read some documentation [here](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643950/understanding-an-email-header) but doesn't say which header is necessary to make a correct non-spam email.

Comment: If you could bypass spam filtering by including the right headers, all the spammers would do it too.   Perhaps the server you're sending from is blacklisted by the receiving ISP.  Check the full headers on the received message that was marked as spam -- that might tell you something about what anti-spam rule it triggered.